# Give an icon to the Gnome Shell 3.6 activities button

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

In previous versions of `gnome-shell` in Gnome 3, it was possible to use an icon in place of the "Activities" text in the left upper corner. [These](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-replace-activities-word-with-any-image-in-gnome-shell/) [tutorials](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2011/04/replace-gnome-shell-activities-text-string-with-icon.html) tell how to achieve this, the second one even providing an extension. It does not work with `gnome-shell` version greater than 3.2, though. Can the icon be brought to the current version, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Activities Configurator extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/) allows to modify, or even hide, icon and text.